# python return only value

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, python-3.7, pyrebase

hello I am using python with firebase but I am not able to execute the code below correctly. I wanted 'data.Child( 'move '). get() ' go only for value but when I run the program gives me the following 'Ordereddict([( 'move', True)]) and I wanted you to give me only True. someone can help me

```
import pyrebase
config = {
  "apiKey": "...",
  "authDomain": "...",
  "databaseURL": "...",
  "projectId": "...",
  "storageBucket": "...",
  "messagingSenderId": "...",
  "appId": "...",
  "measurementId": "..."
};
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
dados = firebase.database()
users = dados.child('mover').get()
mov = users.val()
print(mov)
if mov == 'True':
  print('true')
elif mov == 'False':
  print('false')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `value`, to make it more crystal:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

# creating a simple dict
my_dict = {'move': True}

# creating ordered dict from dict
ordered_dict = OrderedDict(my_dict)

for k,v in ordered_dict.items():
    print(v)
```

OUTPUT:

```
True
```

one-liner:

```
print(list(ordered_dict.values()))   # [True]
```

In your specific case:

```
print(list(mov.values())[0])   # True
```